# Import a text file and replace a values of an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, file, replace, import

I’m a beginner in Java and I'm stuck in one step in my practice where I should import an txt file into an array (using JFileChooser)

The text format is as follow
**001 839 333 426 …**

Where each 3 characters separated by space correspond to **xyz** where
**x**= line number;    **y**= column number;      **v**= value

I have to replace the values in the board based on the coordinates (xy)

```
int [][] board =
{
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },  
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },          
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0 },          
{ 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },          
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },          
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },          
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },          
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },          
{ 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
}
```

If an invalide value is found it should not be used for example 901 (because no line available 9).

Any help or thoughts are very welcome.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking people to design your homework solution for you, which is not something that you should be asking on Stack Overflow. Where, exactly are you stuck? What specific problem are you having when approaching this problem? Be descriptive and specific, or you won't get any answers.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? With creating and opening a File Chooser dialog window or with reading and parsing the data within the file selected with the File Chooser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested finally, I found a way to do the conversion may be not the optimal, but it works:

```
public boolean loadFromFile(String path) {
try {
  int x, y, v;
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(new String());
  Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(path));
  while (file.hasNextLine()) {
    String newLine = file.nextLine();
    sc = new Scanner(newLine);
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
      String xyvalue = sc.next();
      char[] xyv = xyvalue.toCharArray();
      if (xyv.length == 3) {
        x = Character.getNumericValue(xyv[0]);
        y = Character.getNumericValue(xyv[1]);
        v = Character.getNumericValue(xyv[2]);
        if (x >= 0 && x < 9 && y >= 0 && y < 9 && v > 0 && v <= 9) {
          board[x][y] = v;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  sc.close();
  file.close();
  return true;
} catch (IOException exception) {
  return false;
}
```